# Can AWS Amplify do MQTT?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-iot

On the github page https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android it says:

> For new projects, we recommend interacting with AWS using the Amplify Framework.

On the Amplify Framework page about JS developement (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/js), there's a library called PubSub that should do MQTT connection.

But if I switch to Android developement (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/android), that option is not there anymore.

Is there a way to use MQTT with Amplify and GraphQL? Or I need to refer to the android aws sdk and more specifically to this example: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/main/AndroidPubSub/src/com/amazonaws/demo/androidpubsub/PubSubActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [AWS IoT SDK for Android](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html#iot-android-sdk). The AWS IoT SDK uses MQTT as its messaging transport. An example use is [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/main/AndroidPubSub/README.md#android-pubsub-sample). The source code is [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/tree/main/aws-android-sdk-iot). Here is [the artifact in maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-iot/2.16.13).